# JGit status not returning anything from the exisiting repository

Tags: java, git, jgit

Trying to get the status of the repository using JGit status using the below link
https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowStatus.java

But seem like it is not working, on the terminal the git status shows the differences, how on the JGit status it is empty.

On terminal

[image]

**Status code**

```
public static Status GetStatus(String destinationPath) throws GitAPIException, IOException {
    Status status = null;
    try (Git git = Git.open(new File(destinationPath))) {
        status = git.status().call();
    }
    return status;
}
```

There are no changes from the below code

[image]

If I use the below code

```
 try (Repository repository = CookbookHelper.openJGitCookbookRepository()) {
            try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
                Status status = git.status().call();
                System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
                System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
                System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
                System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
                System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
                System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
                System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
                System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
                System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
                System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());
            }
        }
```

It gives me an exceptions as `org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoWorkTreeException: Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index.`